# Saving a single frame (as an image) from a matplotlib funcAnimation

Tags: python, matplotlib

My question is pretty much as titled. I know I can save a video from my animated matplotlib function, but how can I save just a single frame as an image file?

Thanks!

Comment: inside your updater function: `if i == magic_value: fig.savefig(f'fig{i}.png')`

Comment: @PaulH Hm, while that works to take the image, it also freezes the plot (the the GUI). Off the top of your head, is there a reason it might do that? Do I need to somehow restart the animation afterwards, or refresh the plot area?

Comment: that is impossible to answer without an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve